# How can I validate form fields using JavaScript in Multi-step HTML Form?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working on registration form that has three sections. A user moves to the next section of the form when the button "Next" is clicked. Everything is working well except that validation errors are only showing on the last section of the Form. I would like to validate the form before moving to the next section. For now, when "Next" button is clicked, the user can move to the next section even without filling the fields. I'm not so experienced in JavaScript, please help.

HTML:

```
<section>
  <div class="container">
    <form>

      <div class="step step-1 active">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="firstName">First Name</label>
          <input type="text" id="firstName" name="first-name">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="lastName">Last Name</label>
          <input type="text" id="lastName" name="last-name">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="nickName">Nick Name</label>
          <input type="text" id="nickName" name="nick-name">
        </div>
        <button type="button" class="next-btn">Next</button>
      </div>

      <div class="step step-2">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="email">Email</label>
          <input type="text" id="email" name="email">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="phone">Phone</label>
          <input type="number" id="phone" name="phone-number">
        </div>
        <button type="button" class="previous-btn">Prev</button>
        <button type="button" class="next-btn">Next</button>
      </div>

      <div class="step step-3">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="country">country</label>
          <input type="text" id="country" name="country">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="city">City</label>
          <input type="text" id="city" name="city">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="postCode">Post Code</label>
          <input type="text" id="postCode" name="post-code">
        </div>
        <button type="button" class="previous-btn">Prev</button>
        <button type="submit" class="submit-btn">Submit</button>
      </div>

    </form>
  </div>
</section>
```

JavaScript:

```
const steps = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("form .step"));
const nextBtn = document.querySelectorAll("form .next-btn");
const prevBtn = document.querySelectorAll("form .previous-btn");
const form = document.querySelector("form");

nextBtn.forEach((button) => {
  button.addEventListener("click", () => {
    changeStep("next");
  });
});
prevBtn.forEach((button) => {
  button.addEventListener("click", () => {
    changeStep("prev");
  });
});

form.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const inputs = [];
  form.querySelectorAll("input").forEach((input) => {
    const { name, value } = input;
    inputs.push({ name, value });
  });
  console.log(inputs);
  form.reset();
});

function changeStep(btn) {
  let index = 0;
  const active = document.querySelector(".active");
  index = steps.indexOf(active);
  steps[index].classList.remove("active");
  if (btn === "next") {
    index++;
  } else if (btn === "prev") {
    index--;
  }
  steps[index].classList.add("active");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to validate one section of the form before moving on to the next one you should do something like this:

```js
    nextBtn.forEach(button => {
      button.addEventListener("click", () => {
        handleEvent("next")
      })
    })
    prevBtn.forEach(button => {
      button.addEventListener("click", () => {
        handleEvent("prev")
      })
    })
```

where `handleEvent` is:

```js
    function handleEvent(btn) {
      if (!handleFormValidation(btn)) return "error message here";
      changeStep(btn)
    }
```

Here `handleFormValidation` would be a function that checks weather the input is correct and returns `true` if it is and `false` if it isn't

If you want to make sure the user fills in the first form first before going to the second you can do it by making the second form appear only after the `next` button is pressed, but that would require a major rework of your system. (i do however advise it because when i copied your code to test it i noticed quite a lot of bugs)

Here are some mdn articles describing how to make, delete and append elements using javascript:

[making an element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement)

[removing an element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/remove)

[removing an element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/remove)

[appending an element to another element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild)

[appending an element to another element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/append)

I highly encourage you to do your own research as well.

I also just want to apologise if anything in my answer isn't understandable. I'm new at contributing to this community so there will likely be mistakes I've made.